# \f in iOS 9 longer produces a 'soft return', has it been replaced with another escape?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

In iOS 8, I can place `\f` in an `NSAttributedString` and get a return without a paragraph space. This no longer works in iOS 9.

Comment: ``\f`` is a form-feed. I think you wanted `\r`.

Comment: @rmaddy: `\r` will also end the paragraph and space will be added below the line. `\f` until iOS 9, would insert a return without ending the paragraph. (Like hitting shift-return in Word.)

Comment: Update your question with your code for creating the attributed string.

Comment: Notably, you cannot do it using Unicode character (U+2028), LINE SEPARATOR: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=6665236568342528 . I'd love to hear if there is some character that is treated like a line break not a paragraph break